# Is there a way to prohibit copying, deleting, or saving specific file types on disk on Windows 10/11?

Tags: file, security, filesystemwatcher

Is it possible on Windows 10/11 to control the deletion or copying of files of a certain type to the disk. For example, I would like to prohibit the possibility of copying, deleting or saving an excel, pdf, word file to disk?
What would I use if I wanted to write something like this in C#? Maybe there are some system tools? Commercial tools as a last resort?
Regards
Peter

I tried something using DirectorySecurity or FileSystemWatcher but neither of them achieve the goal

Comment: I would investigate which hooks are available for antivirus software.